# ionic 2 - google maps js sdk not working on android device

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ionic2

I read and implement this tutorial :

https://www.joshmorony.com/ionic-2-how-to-use-google-maps-geolocation-video-tutorial/

in the browser(chrome) every things is worked very well but when install and run apk on android device or Genymotion emulator, googel maps is not exist or not showing

Answer (score 0):

sorry for late answer its really too late :D 
well,i fixed it by using `$ npm install --save @ionic-native/google-maps`
 
i followed the same tutorial but giss what you need to install the native blugin :D